# Internationalization i18n with NodeJS and AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, internationalization, angular-translate

I am developing a web application with NodeJS+Express+AngularJS and I am trying to show it in different languages. I have been able to translate correctly static text with "Angular-translate" very easily but the problem is that I don't know to do it with the data that I get dinamically from the database.

I have a column per language (description_es, description_en), so the thing is that I would like to change this statement that I have in the HTML depeding on the selected language.

```
{{restaurant.description_es}}
```

or

```
{{restaurant.description_en}}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$scope.lang = yourActiveLanguage;
....

{{ restaurant['description_' + lang] }}
```